# How can I associate keys from a hashmap to another hashmap (e.g. students to a classroom)?

Tags: java, hashmap, maps

So the basic premise of the problem is that I need to **associate** the keys from a hashmap (students) to another hashmap (classroom), and to do it such a way that I can **print** the students that are in a particular classroom (by printing the classroom), the thing is I don't know how to associate them in the first place (IDK how to **add** students to a classroom). This is what I have:

```
    //HashMaps
    Map<String, String> stud = new HashMap<>();   
    Map<String, String> clar = new HashMap<>();    

   //Populating students (name, age)
    stud.put("Jimmy","12");
    stud.put("Rebecca","12");
    stud.put("Theresa","12");
    stud.put("Ann","12");

   //Populating classroom (number, subject name)
     clar.put("334", "Algebra");
     clar.put("666", "Calculus");
```

Comment: You can associated them by placing the key in the second map, as part of the value in the first map.  I would use a custom class, although you could use a String as you have done.

Comment: Why not use "objects" instead of a hashmap structure which limits you?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Like this:     stud.put("Jimmy","334"); ?

Comment: @LeonHorka that would do it though it would replace your existing value.  You could do `stud.put("Jimmy","12, 334");` although using a custom object would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Create Students in a hashmap and then create a hashmap that contains classroom hashmap with student hashmaps in it.

```
Map<String, String> stud = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<HashMap<String, String>, HashMap<String, String>> clar = new HashMap<HashMap<String, String>, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

*update*

```
HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<String, String>(); // student name, age 
HashMap<String, String> h2 = new HashMap<String, String>();  // classroom number, subject name
HashMap<String, String> h3 = new HashMap<String, String>();  // classroom number, student name
```

Comment: Thanks, so to add a student to a classroom, how would that look? What's my error here:      clar.put(("Jimmy","23"), ("666", "Calculus"));     ?

Comment: Can you add an example of how you would add and lookup values? This could result in a mess if you are not careful.

Comment: Well, when I try this (while using the HashMap structure given by cihan seven): `clar.put(("Jimmy","23"), ("666", "Calculus"));` says "Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to HashMap<String, String>". I really don't know how to add (.put) a student using this method. All I want is to add some students to a class room (and then print out the classroom, so it shows all students in it, but I'm not there yet).

Comment: what i've written is just a theory. It's all your responsibility to manage your data. But i've another theory now: you can define 3 HashMaps like this :  
_answer updated_